# Should non-numerical MPI questions go here or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, topicality

Should general questions on MPI go here or Stack Overflow?  An example of such a question is

```
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/nonblocking-version-of-mpi-barrier-in-mpi-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting my obvious bias as a SciComp mod, I'd prefer that the MPI questions go here. I believe that questions on MPI would be on-topic in both places. Due to the widespread usage of MPI in computational science, I think most MPI questions would be on-topic here. (I hesitate to say "all," because you never know...)

Comment: Great, pretty much what I wanted to hear.  Time to add the next question. :)